# How to use ModelForm with neo4django?

Tags: django, neo4j, neo4django

This seems like a bug but I just want to make sure I'm consuming the API properly.

It seems that support for django's modelform isn't supported on neo4django. Here's what I have:

Simple class:

> from neo4django.db import models
>
> class Person(models.NodeModel):
>       name = models.StringProperty()

The modelform:

> class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
>       class Meta:
>           model = Person

Will trigger exception:

> 'super' object has no attribute 'editable'

I posted details as an issue:
https://github.com/scholrly/neo4django/issues/135

Because when Django goes to lookup field information using the model's _meta information, it finds a BoundProperty instead of a StringProperty or Property (which has a member called 'editable', but BoundProperty doesn't).

Is there a workaround, or is this an actual bug? Any ideas on how to fix the bug? I'm not familiar with the library codebase.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a reasonable (and quick) workaround for anyone using neo4j with Django.

This solution **requires that field names on the form have the exact same name as the attributes of the model**.

Inherit the form from this class and set the model under the form class Meta class:

```
class NeoModelForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(NeoModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._meta = getattr(self, 'Meta', None)
        if not self._meta:
            raise Exception('Missing Meta class on %s' % str(self.__class__.__name__))
        if not hasattr(self._meta, 'model'):
            raise Exception('Missing model on Meta class of %s' % str(self.__class__.__name__))

    def save(self, commit=True):
        if not self.is_valid():
            raise Exception('Failed to validate')
        instance = self._meta.model(**self.cleaned_data)
        if commit:
            instance.save()
        return instance
```

Now you can create a form class like this:

```
class PersonForm(NeoModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput())
    class Meta:
        model = Person
```

And still be able to save a model instance from a valid form:

```
form = formclass(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    obj = form.save()
```

Plus the commit argument will give you the same solution as django's modelform class- but I didn't bother to implement to save_m2m functionality (which doesn't seem relevant for neo4j as a backend).

Comment: For those who haven't seen, ModelForms are now officially supported - https://github.com/scholrly/neo4django/issues/135